# ServiceStack Validation/Serialization

Tags: servicestack, fluentvalidation

I have an application built on ServiceStack and razor (no MVC). The application has a class with an integer field. When I enter an integer with thousand separator(comma) from a web page that allows me to enter data for the field, I get an error with something like "'23,586' is an Invalid value for 'Fieldxx'".

Is there a way to allow integers with thousand separator?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No integers are whole numbers, if you want to keep using an integer I'd recommend your Web Page strip any formatting before sending the API request otherwise change it to a string and convert it into an `int` inside the Service implementation.